# Display Two array values for comparing values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an two product php arrays like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Audio Jack=3.5 mm%%3.5 mm
    [1] => Auto Focus=Yes%%Yes
    [2] => Battery Type=Li-Polymer%%Li-Polymer
    [3] => Battery capacity=1715 mAh%%1715 mAh
)

Array
(
    [0] => Audio Jack=1.5 mm%%1.5 mm
    [1] => Battery Type=Li-Polymer%%Li-Polymer
    [2] => Auto Focus=No%%No
    [3] => Battery capacity=3000 mAh%%3000 mAh
)
```

From this arrays I want to sort that array and display those array values like comparing those two products specification like below table.

Audio Jack          -   3.5 mm      -   1.5 mm

Auto Focus          -   Yes         -   No

Battery Type        -   Li-Polymer  -   Li-Polymer

Battery capacity    -   1715 mAh    -   3000 mAh

Can anyone please help me to display using php.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.  Providing the array always contain the same items and the keys are always the same then this should work.

`$array1 = array(
                    'Audio Jack' => '3.5mm',
                    'Auto Focus' => 'Yes',
                    'Battery Type' => 'Li-Polymer'
                    );
    $array2 = array(
                    'Audio Jack' => '1.5mm',
                    'Auto Focus' => 'no',
                    'Battery Type' => 'Li-Polymer'
                    );
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key.' = '.$value.' - '.$array2[$key].'<br>';
    }`

**Following your update try this.**

```
$array1 = array
(
    'Audio Jack=3.5 mm%%3.5 mm',
    'Auto Focus=Yes%%Yes',
    'Battery Type=Li-Polymer%%Li-Polymer',
    'Battery capacity=1715 mAh%%1715 mAh'
);

$array2 = array
(
   'Audio Jack=1.5 mm%%1.5 mm',
   'Battery Type=Li-Polymer%%Li-Polymer',
   'Auto Focus=No%%No',
   'Battery capacity=3000 mAh%%3000 mAh'
);

foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    $value1 = explode('=', $value);
    $value2 = explode('=', $array2[$key]);

    $result1 = explode('%%', $value1[1]);
    $result2 = explode('%%', $value2[1]);

    echo $value1[0].' = '.$result1[0].' - '.$result2[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $a = [
    'Audio Jack'=>'3.5 mm',
    'Auto Focus'=>'Yes',
    'Battery Type'=>'Li-Polymer',
    'Battery capacity' => '1715 mAh'
];

$b = [
    'Audio Jack'=>'1.5 mm',
    'Auto Focus'=>'No',
    'Battery Type'=>'Li-Polymer',
    'Battery capacity' => '3000 mAh'
];

$combinedArr  = array_merge_recursive($a,$b);

foreach( $combinedArr as $key => $value ){

    echo $key ." - ". implode(" - ", $value) ."<br />";

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was very useful for me.